# Injective dimension of cyclic modules

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-dimension

Let $R$ be a non-Noetherian ring. Is its left global dimension ${\rm{lD}}(R)$ equal to $\sup \{ {\rm{id}}(M) \mid M \text{ is a cyclic $R$-module} \}$? Here $\rm{{id}}(M)$ denotes the injective dimension of $M$.

Comment: What would happen if you had an algebra of the form A\oplus B, and considered B as a cyclic module?  It seems like it should have injective dimension equal to its injective dimension as a B-module.  Then you could give A any properties you wanted which would transfer to A\oplus B (such as higher injective dimension and non-Noetherianness).

Comment: But Greg's comment doesn't contradict anything in the question -- since there would be other cyclic modules (such as A) which would also have higher injective dimensions.  

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no (in general) according to B. L. Osofsky, [Global dimension of valuation rings](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1967-127-01/S0002-9947-1967-0206074-0/S0002-9947-1967-0206074-0.pdf), Corollary 3. For any $1 \leq n \leq \infty$, there are examples where $$\sup \{ {\rm{id}}(M) \mid M \text{ is a cyclic $R$-module} \}=1$$ and ${\rm{lD}}(R)=n$.